# Rails app - Wanting something more than CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app where a `User` controller has all the CRUD methods `new create destroy update`  however, I want an action now that does something more.

When the user clicks a button, I want to perform some logic and then forward them to their accounts page. The logic will go in the new method I make inside the controller.  However, I cant find out how to make a form that submits to this new method I make in the `User` controller.

I'm trying something like this:

`form_tag "/users"`

but how do I make this form execute the new method I've made in the `User` controller

```
def some_logic 
....
end
```

**Update**
After some reading, Is this the best way to go?

routes.rb
match '/download' => "users#some_logic"

view
= form_tag "/download"

This will execute the `some_logic` method

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do in the view:

```
form_tag :action => :some_logic do
```

and in the routes you can have:

```
post "/download", :to => "users#some_logic"
```

That should make a form which sends the user off to the some_logic action within
UsersController

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the docs for further restful actions. You can find it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions